# BMW36 weird high pitched whistle

Tags: noise, bmw

so My E36 3.1.8i  has been making this weird high pitched rattling whistle which sounds like it is coming from either around where the flywheel would be placed is hard to tell exactly where it is coming from as the sound bounces around the engine bay, however I have replace the tensioners thinking it might be that, did not work :(, then replaced the water pump due to thinking the sound was coming from in the block, also no luck the sound is still there, I know that if it was my release bearing on my clutch the sound should disappear when the clutch is pressed in, however this does not happen the sound remains, and if I start her and let her idle she would be fine all the way to warm up but as soon as I give a little rev(Acceleration) she starts whining, Note that this only happens once she starts to warm up, cold start and she's as quiet as a mouse. This has been wrecking my brain, I hope someone out here could try helping out with what it could be, the sound is similar to what you would hear if a bolt was slightly loose and was rubbing up against something.( I hope I am being descriptive enough), I am reaching out as I have replaced here and there to no avail.

Please if anyone has any clue what it could be.

If it helps where I live the speed bumps are a bit high and I have hit the base of my car slightly on one of them, any Ideas on whether there is something down there that could have been knocked to make that sound?

Much Appreciated,

Sincerely,
Some guy pulling all his hair out.LOL